# Generating a client certificate on an Android device

Tags: android, authentication, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I want to create an Android application which will use SSL client certificate authentication.

I have found sample codes which show me how two use SSL client certificate authentication in an Android application. This is clear to me.

My problem is however that I want to generate an SSL client certificate on the device. Simply stated, I want my program to do the following:

When the program is installed on the device, a client certificate should be generated on the device (when running it for the first time), and a public key finger print will be sent to my server. (The certificate must be generated on first use).

How can I generate a client certificate on and Android device from my application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the following code on Android to generate a keypair and retrieve the fingerprint. It uses the excellent [JSCH library from jCraft](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

```
public void generatePublicPrivateKeyPair() throws Exception {

        ByteArrayOutputStream privateKeyOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream publicKeyOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JSch jsch=new JSch();
        KeyPair kpair=KeyPair.genKeyPair(jsch, KeyPair.RSA);
        //kpair.setPassphrase(passphrase);
        kpair.writePrivateKey(privateKeyOutputStream);
        kpair.writePublicKey(publicKeyOutputStream, "Generated by vPro Management Console");

        String fingerPrint = kpair.getFingerPrint();
        System.out.println("Finger print: "+ fingerPrint);
        kpair.dispose();

        byte[] privateKey = privateKeyOutputStream.toByteArray();
        byte[] publicKey = publicKeyOutputStream.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("Private key " + new String(privateKey));
        System.out.println("Public key " + new String(publicKey));


}
```

Simply place the JAR in your libs folder and you're good to go.

If you use maven, you can reference the JSCH dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.50</version>
</dependency>
```